# Computed Column Help - TSQL

Tags: t-sql, calculated-columns

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblLocations](
    [latitude] [float] NOT NULL,
    [longitude] [float] NOT NULL,
    [location] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [point] [geography] AS geography::Point(latitude, longitude, 4326) NOT NULL
)
```

Giving me bad syntax at the word `AS`.

Isn't this how you declare a computed column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't declare the `datatype` or nullability yourself

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblLocations](
    [latitude] [float] NOT NULL,
    [longitude] [float] NOT NULL,
    [location] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [point] AS geography::Point(latitude, longitude, 4326) 
)
```

In general SQL Server will assume the column is nullable [unless you add an `ISNULL()` around the formula](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx).

However I just tried the following column definition

```
[point2] AS ISNULL(geography::Point(latitude, longitude, 4326),
    geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656)', 4326))
```

and that still shows up as `is_nullable` in `sys.computed_columns` so it doesn't look like that applies to CLR datatypes (probably as SQL Server doesn't trust these to be deterministic).

**Edit:** However it *is* syntactically valid to specify `NOT NULL` as long as the computed column is marked as `PERSISTED` i.e.

```
[point] AS geography::Point(latitude, longitude, 4326) PERSISTED NOT NULL
```

In this particular case however attempting to create a table with such a definition gives a runtime error.

> Computed column 'point' in table
>   'foo' cannot be persisted because the
>   column type, 'geography', is a
>   non-byte-ordered CLR type.

Comment: Oh okay so the type get's declared by the calculation - duh makes sense. And whos to say it can't be null unless you perform the proper checks. Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: Actually for CLR datatypes it might always assume it is Nullable. I just tried wrapping in `ISNULL` and it still shows up as `is_nullable` in `sys.computed_columns`