# How do you add a computed column to a Table?

Tags: t-sql, ddl

How can I add a computed column to a table that already exists? S.O. has [Computed Column Help - TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5841876/456188) but no information about adding them.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The syntax I was looking for is:

```
alter table TABLE_NAME
add [column_name] as (**COLUMN-SQL**)
```

Comment: `alter table TABLE_NAME add [column_name] as (**COLUMN-SQL**)`

Comment: EX: `alter table TABLE_NAME add [double_count] as (count * 2)`

Comment: To create a persisted column (calculated when the data is inserted) you can add the Persisted keyword: alter table TABLE_NAME
add [column_name] as (COLUMN-SQL) **PERSISTED**

Comment: THis does now work when adding Row_Number column. 
ALTER TABLE MYDB.[dbo].[Table1]
ADD Rn INT NOT NULL AS (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [MyColumn] ORDER BY [MyColumn]));

Comment: I imagine that's a result of using a windowing function in a calculated column.