# Calculate values after insert directly in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a mysql database with four columns: *date*, *time when gotten up*, *time when gone to bed* and *hours slept*. Everyday, the date and both times are entered via an html form using php. My goal is to automatically calculate the hours slept and insert them *using only the database*. I have implemented something similar like this with `DOUBLE AS` in the past but the problem in my current case is that I need the bedtime **from the day / row before** to do this.

**So my question is this**: In mysql (or another rdbms), is there a way to calculate the difference of two values which belong to different columns and different rows of a table whenever a new row is inserted?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is something along the lines of...

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
    BEFORE UPDATE ON table_name
    FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE table_name
    SET hours_slept = HOUR(TIMEDIFF(time_when_gotten_up, time_when_gone_to_bed))
    WHERE hours_slept IS NULL;
```

Comment: Yes, this would be one of the correct approaches, the one I'd prefer but also there's another fun way called Calculated Columns, you might check that too.  here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058387/how-do-you-add-a-computed-column-to-a-table

Comment: This seems to use time_when_gotten_up and time_when_gone_to_bed from the same row, while I need to use the bedtime from the day / row before. Or am I misunderstanding what's happening?

Comment: Thanks @Musical Coder, I was able to create a solution starting from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Musical Coder's answer as a template, I was able to create a working solution with subqueries and DATE_SUB():

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
    BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
    FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.hours_slept =
    HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NEW.sleep_end, (SELECT sleep_start FROM table_name WHERE day = DATE_SUB(NEW.day, INTERVAL 1 DAY))))
    + MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(NEW.sleep_end, (SELECT sleep_start FROM table_name WHERE day = DATE_SUB(NEW.day, INTERVAL 1 DAY)))) / 60;
```